# Issue with jQuery validate not working against element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I am having an issue using jQuery validate against a form in a current project.

I am sure it is a typo I am missing or something small, but can't sem to figure out why it is occurring.

The error I am getting in the console debugger is: Object doesn't support property or method 'validate'

The bundle configuration file:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/custom").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/ContactForm.js"));
```

The code snippets are below:

```
<form action="@Url.Action("UpdateContactInformation", "ContactController")"  method="post" role="form" class="form-horizontal" id="contactForm">
<input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='brGfMU16YyyG2QEcpLqhb3Zh8AvkYkJt' />
<!-- First Name Form Field-->
<div class="form-group required">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">First Name</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <input class="form-control" id="id_firstName" maxlength="75" name="txtFirstName" placeholder="First Name" required="required" title="" type="text" />
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Last Name Form Field-->
<div class="form-group required">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Last Name</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <input class="form-control" id="id_lastName" maxlength="75" name="txtlastName" placeholder="Last Name" required="required" title="" type="text" />
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Title Form Field-->
<div class="form-group required">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Title</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <input class="form-control" id="id_title" maxlength="75" name="txtTitle" placeholder="Title" required="required" title="" type="text" />
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Address Form Field-->
<div class="form-group required">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Address</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <input class="form-control" id="id_address" maxlength="75" name="txtAddress" placeholder="Address" required="required" title="" type="text" />
    </div>
</div>
<!-- City Form Field-->
<div class="form-group required">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">City</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <input class="form-control" id="id_city" maxlength="75" name="txtCity" placeholder="City" required="required" title="" type="text" />
    </div>
</div>
<!-- State Form Field-->
<div class="form-group required">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">State</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuStates" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
            Select State
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="statesDropDownMenu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuStates">

        </ul>
    </div>
        </div>
</div>
<!-- Zip Form Field-->
<div class="form-group required">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">ZipCode</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <input class="form-control" id="id_zipCode" maxlength="75" name="txtZipCode" placeholder="ZipCode" required="required" title="" type="number" />
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Email Primary Form Field-->
<div class="form-group required">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Email Primary</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <input class="form-control customEmail" id="id_emailPrimary" maxlength="75" name="txtEmailPrimay" placeholder="Email Primary" required="required" />
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Email Secondary (optional) Form Field-->
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Email (Optional)</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <input class="form-control" id="id_emailSecond" maxlength="75" name="txtEmailSecond" placeholder="Email (Optional)"  title="Email (Optional)" type="email" />
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Email Third (optional) Form Field-->
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Email (Optional)</label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <input class="form-control" id="id_emailThird" maxlength="75" name="txtEmailThird" placeholder="Email (Optional)" title="Email (Optional)" type="email" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Submit Contact Info
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval");
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/custom");  //contains the file I am trying to add $.validate.AddMethod() to

Here is the code for Contact.js

```
$.validator.addMethod(
         "customEmail",
         function (value, element) {
             var re = new RegExp("/^@{0,2}\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*@{0,2}​‌‌​​$/");
             return this.optional(element) || re.test(value);
         },
         "Please enter a valid email address."
    );

$(document).ready(function () {

    console.log("Were here.........");

   // populateStatesDropDown();



    $('#contactForm').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        rules: {
            txtZipCode: {
                required: true,
                numeric: true
            },
            txtEmailPrimay: {
                required: true,
                customEmail:true
            },
            txtEmailSecond:{
                required:false,
                customEmail:true,
            },
            txtEmailThird: {
                required: false,
                customEmail:true
            }
        }
    });



    populateStatesList();

});

function populateStatesList() {
    var url = "Contact/GetStates"; // Don't hard code your url's!
    //$("#province_dll").change(function () {
    var $statesDropDownMenu = $("#statesDropDownMenu"); // Use $(this) so you don't traverse the DOM again
    var listItems = '';
        $.getJSON(url, function (response) {
            $statesDropDownMenu.empty(); // remove any existing options
            console.log(response);
            $.each(response, function (index, item) {
                console.log("Now - " + item);

                listItems += "<li>" + item + "</li>";                
            });

            $statesDropDownMenu.html(listItems);
        });
    //});
}
```

Comment: It sounds like `jquery.validate.min.js` is not loaded on your page. Check your network tab and make sure you see that file with a status of 200. Or you could have a syntax error in your `<form id="contactForm">` declaration. Check your source code and make sure your ASP is producing the expected HTML.

Comment: Yea, I checked that already ad shows it is loaded before my Contact.js file gets loaded. Thanks though. I load it after I load the bundle that contains jquery.validate.js

Comment: The debugger shows it gets through the contact.js file so gets passed the $.validator special method to be added, but fails when trying to init the plugin at $('#contactForm').validate({ }) line.

Comment: What does `console.log($('#contactForm').length);` produce?

Comment: It returns a val of 1. I also was wondering if it was not there at the run time. Could this posibly mean that an element inside the form cannot be validated and so it fails on the line showing it is init the "validate" method...

Comment: I think `$.validator.addMethod(` is being called before the JS file has been loaded. Try putting everything inside `$(document).ready(function(){`

Comment: You have a extra comma.

Comment: I think you are on to something. When I moved it into the document ready, i get the following console error: Unable to get property 'addMethod' of undefined or null reference   So let me try a few things, and track down how it is rendering and what order.

Comment: Try working with the smallest set of code possible to reproduce the issue such as a simple `<form>` with a single textbox and no custom validator methods. Add your fancyness one-by-one and you will quickly see where your code fails. Trying to debug such a large codebase is silly if you can't even discern the basics.

Comment: I think your problem is not in the code you have posted, which looks correct and [seems to work flawlessly](https://jsfiddle.net/Lhjb4otq/). Anyway, I would fix the quotes in the form action.

Comment: Good idea, I will break it down and try to find it. I thought maybe there was something I was missing.  Thanks everyone for the help. Let me pound away at this for few minutes, then will post any findings and updates. Thaanks everyone as always in this great community.

Comment: I wonder if I should just use the thml validations for now, and add my custom regexp patter to it, then come back to this issue to post an answer for it. I will keep looking into it though.

Answer (score -2):

You have an extra comma.

```
txtEmailSecond:{
        required:false,
        customEmail:true, // Here
},
```

Comment: Ahh, let me see.  I was worried it was an overlooking of that sort.

Comment: Javascript has no issues with a trailing comma like that. If I saw two commas then it would produce an unexpected token error.

Comment: I thought about that right after I replied. Let me update my question to display the bundles config page, and see why it would't be loading in order as expected.

Comment: As says @MonkeyZeus the extra comma isn't a problem.